# Smooch iframe disables all clickable elements

Tags: javascript, chatbot, smooch

[image]

The default Smooch code to embed it on websites, disables all links covered by the iframe. How can this be fixed?

Comment: have you tried using the z-index?

Comment: Yes, unchecking the z-index fixes the issue, but the Smooch iframe has a dynamic class (not even an ID), so it cannot be easily targeted to change the z-index. They are using z-index: 9998 by default :-/

Answer (score 0):

It was my fault. I had some CSS code messing around with iframes